# Why we use "&" here: insert(&(*root)->left,value); But we do not use "&" here: search(root->left, value);

Tags: c, pointers, tree, double, binary-tree

```
void instert(NODE**root, int value)
{
    ...
    insert(&(*root)->left,value);
    ...
}

void search(NODE*root, int value)
{
    ...
    search(root->left, value);
    ...
}
```

Why we use `&` here: `insert(&(*root)->left,value);` But we do not use `&` here: `search(root->left, value);`

Comment: One needs a `NODE **` and the other needs a `NODE *`. The address of operator returns a pointer to the operand.

Comment: Sorry its my 1st time on Stack Overflow. My 1st question was bad.

Comment: @AdrianPrzemysławDrozdowski: If at all, improve it then. At least, don't ask an improved duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It is a way to introduce references in C. In the first case function insert can change pointer `left` If it will be passed by value as it is done in function `serach` then any changes of the parameter of function insert will not be applied to the original pointer. Thus the function accepts the argument "by reference".

In the second case when function search is used pointer left is not changed.

That it would be more clear consider the following example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f( char **p )
{
   free( *p );
   *p = ( char * )malloc( sizeof( char ) );
   **p = 'B';
}

void g( char *p )
{
   printf( "%c\n", *p );
}

int main()
{
   char *p = ( char * )malloc( sizeof( char ) );
   *p = 'A';

   g( p );

   f( &p );

   g( p );

   free( p );
}
```

If function f would not accept pointer "by reference" then the value of the original point would not be changed.

Consider modified code and compare their execution results

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f( char *p )
{
   free( p ); // OOPS! memory was freed
   p = ( char * )malloc( sizeof( char ) );
   *p = 'B';
}

void g( char *p )
{
   printf( "%c\n", *p );
}

int main()
{
   char *p = ( char * )malloc( sizeof( char ) );
   *p = 'A';

   g( p );

   f( p ); // after the call the program behaviour is undefined.

   g( p );

   free( p );
}
```

Comment: Nope, the expression is valid, since `root` is of type `NODE **`

Comment: @Drew McGowen  TIn this case the other expression root->left is invalid.

Comment: So if root is a type NODE * we do not need "&" ?

Comment: @Vlad assuming `root->left` is also of type `NODE *`, then it's also valid. Both expressions (minus the `instert` misspelling) are valid.

Comment: @Drew McGowen You do not know the priority of operators. Either the first or the second expression is invalid.

Comment: @Adrian Przemysław Drozdowski I have not understood why you did such a conclusion.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow [Both expressions are valid.](http://ideone.com/pJL6hp)

Comment: @Drew McGowen You defined root differently in both cases. Assuming that root has the same type in both cases then one of expressions is invalid.

Comment: Adrian Przemysław Drozdowski  See my updated post.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow your assumption is incorrect. They're defined differently between the two functions.

Comment: @Drew McGowen it seems the original post was updated.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow aside from a formatting fix, nothing was functionally changed in the code.

Comment: @Drew McGowen Maybe it is me who did not take into account that the same name was defined differently. What is the problem?!